# In Angular2, while I have a named outlet open, how can I navigate to another route with matrix param AND close the named outlet?

Tags: angular

I'm using named outlets to show a sidebar. Works fine:

```
router.navigate(['/', {outlets: {sidebar: 'profile'}}])
```

I also have a button which on click, closes the sidebar. Also works fine:

```
router.navigate(['/', {outlets: {sidebar: null}}])
```

The other button should close the sidebar and route to contacts with matrix parameters

```
router.navigate(['/', {outlets: {sidebar: null, primary: "contacts"}}]">
```

I'm able to route but **unable** to pass parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you've tried so far, but would something like this work?

```
router.navigate(['/', {outlets: {sidebar: null, 
                       primary: ["/contacts", {field: value}]}}]"
```

Comment: Hi Deborah, Thanks for your reply. I never knew that I can pass an array for primary attribute. It worked!!.